# Get the background of another elements when clicked toggle navigation bar

Tags: jquery, css, background, navigation, toggle

I'm newbie and I get some problems with the background when I clicked the toggle navigation bar. I have no ideal how i can get this background. That means when you clicked the button hamburger, the navigation will appear and the rest will become dark. Is it something about blur or opacity or something?
Please help me to solve this problems.
Thank you very much!
(you can see this image to understand more what I mentioned)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqvCn.jpg

Comment: Please add some sample code to understand your problem more clear

Comment: It will be very helpfull to us and to you also if you add code in the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use box shadow

```css
.box{display:inline-block; width:100px; height:100px; margin-top:50px; text-align:center; padding-top:2em}
.box.selected{
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 99999px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Box 1</div>
<div class="box">Box 2</div>
<div class="box selected">Box 3</div>
<div class="box">Box 4</div>
```